# Azure and .Net services

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm fairly confused about the differences between the Azure and .Net .
Do .Net services run on the Azure platforms or are they two different things?
I'm currently learning .Net and C#.
Are those .Net skills and knowledge still useful even if I decided to persuade the career of cloud engineering on Azure platform ?

Comment: Being proficient in C#/.Net surely does not hurt when going into Azure. Confusion will fluctuate _a lot_ along the journey. Just enjoy the ride.

Comment: Azure is a cloud provider similar to Aws or Google Cloud. They provide certain services so that you don’t have to manage them yourself. Thinks like storage, hosting, databases etc. C# and .net are unrelated to Azure in that sense but you can connect to these Azure Services with them (as well as a multitude of other languages) or potentially host your code on them. Programming knowledge is “technically” not needed but having it will help you go a lot further

Answer (score 0):

```
Do .Net services run on the Azure platforms or are they two different things?
```

Yes, .Net services runs on the azure platform and along with that we can also run other programming languages like **java**, **python**, **node.js** etc.

.NET Services is a component that makes up part of the Azure platform.

- Azure composed of the operating environment and the base services that are used to host cloud applications. It provides the base capabilities (web and worker processes) as well as the simple data storage offerings.
- .NET Services are the services that many applications will use to create cloud scale applications, although originally the services were mostly geared toward enterprise development. It includes the access service and service bus.

There are also a few other services that are provided in azure:

- SQL Azure is the SQL Server for the cloud offering. It is used like a regular SQL Server instance, for the most part, but is hosted and serviced by Microsoft.

One thing to note is that, although these services are offered as part of the Azure platform, the .NET Services should be usable from any platform.

```
Are those .Net skills and knowledge still useful even if I decided to persuade the career of cloud engineering on Azure platform ?
```

Yes, .Net skills and knowledge obviously helps you to better understand the development of applications and deployment to Azure App Services as well quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Q> Do .Net services run on the Azure platforms or are they two different things?

A> Yes, of course .net run on Azure platform, but .net and Azure are different things. Azure provide service that you can host your .net application with them. Azure is cloud hosting provider, it is similar like AWS and also Google Cloud.

If you are new in deploying website, I believe you don't need to go with Azure since Azure will be quite costly if you also use SQL server database. Plus it is quite difficult to use for beginner. It will better for you to find shared hosting provider that support .NET service. For example, Asphostportal is shared hosting provider that fully support .NET. You will be given access to control panel. So, you can easily create your domain, database, FTP, email account, etc via that control panel and it is definitely will be cheaper than Cloud technology.

Q>  Are those .Net skills and knowledge still useful even if I decided to persuade the career of cloud engineering on Azure platform ?

A> Absolutely yes. Without any .net skills, how can you deploy your website?